# understanding Javascript recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to wrap my head around recursive functions, and I do not understand the output (this example is from John Resig's 'Javascript Ninja' book):

```
var ninja = {
  chirp: function chirp(n) {
    return (n > 1) ? chirp(n-1) + "-chirp"+n : "chirp"+n;
  }
}

$('#hello').html(ninja.chirp(8));
```

and the output:

> chirp1-chirp2-chirp3-chirp4-chirp5-chirp6-chirp7-chirp8

Why is the output of `n` increasing instead of decreasing? It seems to me that the output would count down from 8 instead of up from 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/9xq7j6y8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `chirp(1)` the result will be `"chirp1"`.

If you call `chirp(2)` the result will be `chirp(1) + "-chirp2"`, i.e. `"chirp1-chirp2"`.

If you call `chirp(3)` the result will be `chirp(2) + "-chirp3"`, i.e. `"chirp1-chirp2-chirp3"`.

As you see, the function calls itself to get the output for the lower numbers, and adds the highest number last.

Comment: I almost get it... I understand that the function returns only once, but is n being increased in the output, or are the returned values being pushed?

Comment: @superUntitled: In recursion it's common to divide the work into smaller parts. In this case the work for a call like `chirp(8)` is dividied into the parts "1 to 7" and "8". The method does a recursive call for the first part, and does the last part itself. The order in the result simply is because the parts are put together as "1 to 7" + "8" rather than "8" + "1 to 7".

Answer (score 1):

It is counting down from 8, but the output is getting appended to the beginning of the string, and then you're reading the output from left to right.

If you saw the output as it was being built, it would look like:

```
-chirp8
-chirp7-chirp8
-chirp6-chirp7-chirp8
...
chirp1-chirp2-chirp3-chirp4-chirp5-chirp6-chirp7-chirp8
```

Since you only see the final output, it shows up in ascending order.

Comment: So the returned values are getting pushed?

Comment: @Guffa has the correct answer. Yes, the string values get pushed on the stack as each recursive call is made. The appending happens in the JS string concatenation code, not in the jQuery .append.